# Определить на какое место ImageView расположенного на виджете нажали

Tags: android, android-widgets

У меня есть виджет с ImageView. На нем нарисовано несколько картинок одинакового размера с известным размером. Мне нужно определить на какое место ImageView нажали. Остальное я определю. Возможно ли такое сделать с виджетом?

Answer (score 0):

По-моему это возможно только зная координаты ImageView.

Посмотрите здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970636/how-to-check-which-image-side-is-pressed?noredirect=1&lq=1

И здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038867/android-how-to-detect-touch-location-on-imageview-if-the-image-view-is-scaled-b

Comment: проблема в том, что в виджете доступ к его элементам осуществляется через RemoteViews, а у него кроме setOnClickPendingIntent ничего более нет